# Can we please lock this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-question

[Dealing with engineers that frequently leave their jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43409/dealing-with-engineers-that-frequently-leave-their-jobs)

It's true. This question does not meet the core criteria for this site.

But it generated some fantastic answers.

Can we please lock this question so that others may learn from it too?

Comment: +1 [top voted answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/43413/31260) stands out indeed. A handful other answers look pretty decent, too. Locking may be a reasonable option

Comment: Hm, why? It's not in any danger of getting deleted and more importantly it was last active today. Locking prevents any further activity on the question or its answers, what would be the point of locking it?

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: I thought that a closed question may be deleted at any time. Am I mistaken? Also, I don't think this question will ever be eligible for re-opening. Am I mistaken? // I just don't want to lose such great answers. I actually think that this question should be seriously considered for the blog.

Comment: I flagged the question to be moved to http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @songo Please don't flag old questions for migration, we won't migrate any of them, especially to beta sites (unless the target site's community asks for them specifically).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question doesn't really qualify for the [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) (emphasis mine):

> ### When is it appropriate to lock a question for historical reasons?
>
> Questions can be historically locked when:
>
> - The post is Off-Topic or Not Constructive, and
> - The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and
> - There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, and
> - **The post is contentious; i.e. it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once**

If the question remains closed:

- There is a risk of it being deleted at some later point. We rarely delete highly upvoted questions without very good reason, however I can't promise that three 10K+ users or a fellow moderator won't vote to delete it.
- It and its answers are still editable and can be voted on (including re-open votes for the question)
- It appears in site searches.

If the question gets a historical lock:

- It will be frozen as is, no more edits or (any kind of) votes.
- It won't appear in site searches, and will only be accessible via its url.

The historical lock is more intended for questions that are already deleted or, for whatever reason, are very close to being deleted. For example if we where doing an organized cleanup, similar to [stci](/questions/tagged/stci) and we were targeting [project-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) questions, then yes, it would make sense to lock it. But right now the question isn't really on a path to deletion, or if you prefer that path is extremely long, it already survived [stci](/questions/tagged/stci) (check [revision 5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/43409/revisions)).

I wouldn't mind locking it, the whole process is just a click of a button really, but given that one of its answers was edited earlier today, and the question has a pending re-open vote, it seems that its current state is preferable. Is there a very specific reason we should froze it?

Comment: +1: In light of your explanation, 'No'. Thanks a lot, Yannis.